# Pasting strings outside of Xcode to an array doesn't regonize them as strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

so after a long time writing down all different currencies i need for my currency converter i was going to paste them into Xcode. But when i do that the text doesn't turn red. Im afraid i need to rewrite it all string again, which took my almost 1h to do. Is there any way to fix this?

```
 Datarray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"United States Dollar",@”Euro”,@”Japanese yen”,@”Bulgarian lev”,@”Czech koruna”,@”Danish krone”,@”British pound”,@”Hungarian forint”@”Lithuanian litas”,@”Polish złoty”,@”Romanian leu”,@”Swedish krona”,@”Swiss franc”,@”Norwegian krone”,@”Croatian kuna”,@”Russian ruble”,@”Turkish lira”,@”Australian dollar”,@”Brazilian real”,@”Canadian dollar”,”Chinese yuan”,@”Hong Kong dollar”,@”Indonesian rupiah”,@”Israeli new shekel”,@”Indian rupee”,@South Korean won”,@”Mexican peso”,@”Malaysian ringgit”,@”New Zealand dollar”,@”Philippine peso”,@”Singapore dollar”,@”Thai baht”,@”South African rand”,nil];
```

EDIT: interestly, they don't show as string here at stackoverflow either outside from US Dollar which i wrote from inside xcode.

Comment: By the way, Welcome to stack overflow! Please up vote answers that helped and tick answers that solved - be a part of the community :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the text, the quotes are wrong. You have `”`, but should have `"` (and the first USD one does).

Global find and replace the wrong quotes with the correct quotes.